# Cognito User Pools & Access Tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am hoping to use Cognito and User Pools to support a multitenant environment. So far it checks most of the boxes. It is my understanding that there is no current way to enrich the access token using Lambda triggers. I would really like to pass something to identify which user pool the user authenticated with in the access token to my APIs. Am I missing something or is there a workaround for this?

One option that came to mind is to create a group in each to which all members of the pool are members off that is either the name or combination of the name and tenant id. Is this a reasonable approach or a horrible idea? something like tenant_1234. Then I believe this group would be included in the access token and can be parsed to get the id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may had misunderstood the question, however access token payload contains the user pool Id https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-access-token.html#user-pool-access-token-payload

> Issuer (iss)
> The iss claim has the following format:
> https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}.

You can also add the custom scopes to the access token to customize the payload further

Comment: No you didn't misunderstand. Everything I has found said that access tokens can't be customized but Id tokens can.  But either of these helps a lot.

Comment: @MViglainco if you found answer useful consider marking it as correct

Comment: I don't know if it's correct yet but ok